# does cordova support localStorage for OS X?

Tags: cordova, local-storage

I'm trying to persist some data on a angular/cordova App, and localStorage seems a reasonable solution for what I need, but I'm super confused by the documentation and I'm not sure if cordova supports localStorage on Mac. On the [platform support page](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/support/index.html) storage is marked with a red x for OS X, but on the [storage page](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html#advantages) it is stated that localStorage is supported by all Cordova platforms.

any help or useful documentation is much much appreciated. In case it's not supported what's the recommended way to persist a string for all the platforms available?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it supports localStorage on any iPhone device.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build an OSX app via `cordova-ios` and then build as MacOSX (universal app) as well, or do you use the MacOSX platform ?
I believe now you can build straight from `cordova-ios` and check, in xcode: mac as targets and uncheck iphone, ipad. It should still use the same webview and then `localstorage` should be available (xcode universal app)